# Order statistics and biased estimators

Tags: statistics, uniform-distribution

Would someone be able to check my work on this question:

> Suppose that $Y_1,Y_2,...,Y_5$ is a random sample from a uniform distribution over the interval (0, theta). Determine if the followng estimators for theta are unbiased or biased
>
> > a) $\theta = \dfrac{2}{5}(Y_1 + Y_2 +Y_3 + Y_4 + Y_5)$
> >
> > b) $\theta = Y_{(5)}$, the fifth order statistic

a) $\theta = \dfrac{2}{5}(Y_1 + Y_2 +Y_3 + Y_4 + Y_5)$
$$E(\theta) = E(\dfrac{2}{5}(Y_1 + Y_2 +Y_3 + Y_4 + Y_5))$$
$$ = \dfrac{2}{5}E((Y_1 + Y_2 +Y_3 + Y_4 + Y_5))$$
$$ = \dfrac{2}{5}(E(Y_1) + E(Y_2) + E(Y_3) + E(Y_4) + E(Y_5))$$
$$E(Y_i) = \dfrac{0+\theta}{2} = \dfrac{\theta}{2}$$
$$E(\theta) = \dfrac{2}{5}(\dfrac{\theta}{2} + \dfrac{\theta}{2} + \dfrac{\theta}{2} + \dfrac{\theta}{2} + \dfrac{\theta}{2})
 = \dfrac{2}{5}(\dfrac{5 \theta}{2}) = \theta$$

Thus, the estimator is biased

b)

$$g_(5) = n[F(y)]^{n-1} f(y)$$

$$F(y) = \int_{0}^{y} \dfrac{1}{\theta} dt = \dfrac{y}{\theta}$$
$$g_(5) = 5[\frac{y}{\theta}]^4 (\dfrac{1}{\theta}) = \dfrac{5y^4}{\theta^5}$$
$$E(\theta) = E(\dfrac{5y^4}{\theta^5}) = y*\dfrac{5y^4}{\theta ^5} = \dfrac{5y^5}{\theta ^5}$$

Thus, the estimator is biased

I felt really uncertain of my work, I really appreciate any help! Thanks in advanced!

Comment: I forgot to integrate with the expected value. b) should instead be $$E(\theta) = \dfrac{5}{7}(\theta^7)$$ Thanks again for helping!

Answer (score 1):

Your calculation of (a) is correct, but your conclusion should say "unbiased," since you found that the expectation equals the parameter.

Regarding (b), I would proceed from more elementary principles:  $$\begin{align*} F_{Y_{(5)}}(y) &= \Pr[Y_{(5)} \le y] \\ &= \prod_{i=1}^5 \Pr[Y_i \le y] \\ &= (F_{Y}(y))^5 \\ &= (y/\theta)^5, \end{align*}$$ hence $$f_{Y_{(5)}}(y) = 5y^4/\theta^5, \quad 0 \le y \le \theta.$$  Up to this point, your solution is correct.  However, it follows that $$\operatorname{E}[Y_{(5)}] = \int_{y=0}^\theta y \cdot \frac{5y^4}{\theta^5} \, dy = \frac{5}{\theta^5} \left[ \frac{y^6}{6} \right]_{y=0}^\theta = \frac{5}{6}\theta.$$  Therefore this estimator is biased.  You can also see how to modify this estimator to make it unbiased in the general case of a sample size of $n \ge 1$; e.g., you could choose $$\hat\theta = \frac{n+1}{n} Y_{(n)}.$$

Answer (score 0):

For the second problem, you can say directly that the estimator is biased for $\theta$ without doing any calculation. Since each of the $Y_i$s are less than $\theta$ with probability 1, clearly the highest order statistic is also less than $\theta$ with probability 1. Hence $E(Y_{(5)})<\theta$